# checkIfRowExists() in sqlite doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

**Edit**
The problem is solved. The method `checkIfRowExists()` method is working correctly. The problem was that the `Button Listener` was changing the `date` to a wrong format. The `DatePicker` used 05 for days and the `Button` 5 without 0.

**My App**
shows a `ListView` with `CheckBoxes`. The state of the `CheckBoxes` is saved for each `row` for a specific `date`. The `date` can be choosen via `DatePicker` or by clicking a right or left `Button` to go to the next or previous day.
I'm using `SQLite` to save the data. My `table` has six `columns`:

```
ID (Primary Key)  Date  ItemName  StateCB1  StateCB2  StateCB3
```

If the user chooses a new `date`, the method `checkIfRowExists(String date, String itemName)` checks if a `row` exists for the specific `ListItem` and `date`. If not a new `row` gets created.

**My Problem**
Let's assume there is no data saved in the `database`, yet.
The user chooses the `date 01.Jan.2000` via `DatePicker`. The method `checkIfRowExists()` gets called for each `row` for the given `date`. The method returns `false`, because there is no data in the `database` and new `rows` for each `listItem` for the given `date` are getting created. The user checks all `CheckBoxes`. The `table` gets updated.
Now the user chooses the same `date` by clicking the `LeftButton`. So he goes to the `date 02.Jan.2000` , clicks `leftButton` and now the `date 01.Jan.2000` gets choosen. Again the `checkIfRowExists()` methods get called for each `row` for the given `date`. This time it should return `true`, because data exists for this `date`.

> The Problem, the `checkIfRowExists()` method returns `false` instead of `true` and new `rows` are created.
>   Now there are redundant `rows`.

If the user chooses the `date 01.Jan.2000` a second time via `DatePicker` or `LeftButton` the `checkIfRowExists()` method returns `true`. But because two `rows` for each `date` and `item` now exists, changes in `CheckBox state` are now saved seperately. The `state` of the `CheckBoxes` gets saved seperately for `date` choosen by `DatePicker` and `date` choosen by `LeftButton`.

I can't find my mistake. I already browsed through stackoverflow, but couldn't find an answer. I think the problem is within the checkIfRowExists() method.

**checkIfRowExists() is getting called here in Adapter Class:**
The `date` and `itemTitle` are correct. So that's not the problem.

```
//Check if row exists
            Boolean exists = mDB.checkIfRowExists(MainActivity.date, item.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Does row exist? " + exists );
            if(!exists){
                //create new row
                mDB.addRow(MainActivity.date, item.getTitle());
            }
            //load data
            boolean[] stateCheckBox = mDB.getCheckBoxState(MainActivity.date, item.getTitle());
```

**checkIfRowExists() in DBHelper class**

```
//Check if row already exists
public boolean checkIfRowExists(String date, String itemName){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    boolean exists = true;
    System.out.println("checkIfRowExists:" + date + " " + itemName);
    String checkQuery = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + DBTABLE_StateCB +
            " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE + "= '" + date + "'" +
            " AND " + COLUMN_ITEM + " = '" + itemName + "'" ;
    cursor = mDB.rawQuery(checkQuery, null);
    exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

**DatePicker**

```
   DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
        mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                //Change date
                setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth); 

                //Update ListView 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Button Listener that changes date**

```
//Click on left Button
    leftBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //Change Date to previous day
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try{
                Date prevDate = format.parse(date);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(prevDate);
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                Date mydate = cal.getTime();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                try {
                    date = sdf.format(mydate);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               /* mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                date = (mYear + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mDay); */
            }catch (ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Set Left/Right Button
            setBTN();

            //Update ListView 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```